# How to display broken Japanese text correctly of exported PDF using dompdf?

Tags: pdf, export, pdf-generation, break, magento2.4

I would like to export Japanese PDF using Dompdf.
Currently, PDF export is working correctly.

```
        `$dompdf = new Dompdf();
        $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

        //$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');            
        $dompdf->load_html($html, 'UTF-8');
        $dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true); // Enable HTML5 parser
        $dompdf->set_option('defaultFont', 'CyberCJK'); // Set a font that supports Japanese characters
        $dompdf->set_option('margin', '10mm');
        $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
        $dompdf->render();
        $output = $dompdf->output();
        $mediaPath = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()-               
         >get(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::class)-
         >getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
        $pdfFile = file_put_contents($mediaPath . "/Uedakanamono/netprint/".$id."_card.pdf", $output);
        return $id."_card.pdf";`
```

But Japanese is broken.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kH1m2.png)
What should I do?
Help me. please post example code.